# parsing xml file manually with r

Tags: r

for some reason, I cannot download the r xml package at work. I have an xml file that has contents like this:

```
x<-read.table("info.xml")
```

x

```
</name></content></item><item id="id-123"><content><name>
</name></content></item><item id="id-456"><content><name>
</name></content></item><item id="id-5559"><content><name>
```

I need to pick values that start with id and - and the numbers like

id-123, id-456 id-5559, etc

tried this:

```
str_extract_all(x, "id-[0-9]")
```

but is only printing id-1, I really need help very quick. Any ideas?

Comment: no it is not prank, for some reason, the contents of x did not show on the site.

Comment: I would much rather help you figure out how to download the XML package successfully.

Comment: What @joran said. But if you insist as using XML as overly formatted ASCII files, there are about 10^5 tutorials about regular expressions out there.  Read one or two and it all should become clear.

Comment: If you cant download it at work, download it at home and bring it in to work on a USB stick.

Comment: @joran, I can download any other package but xml from cran. Not sure if the package is not available?

Comment: I can assure you that the package is "available". If you want help installing XML, edit your question to include exactly what you tried (e.g. `install.packages("XML")`) and show us exactly what happened that went wrong.

Comment: virus scanner is blocking the download of this package. sorry for the all this questions, I really needed this.

Comment: dont understand why this post is being down voted. I needed this done and asked, isn't this what this site for.

Answer (score 1):

str_extract_all(x, "id-[0-9]+")

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression "id-[0-9]" is missing a "+" at the end.
There may be more issues, but that one jumps out.